# In a Rust repository there is a package with a dash "-" in the name, how do I "use" in Rust code?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to use the async-process crate/package in rust code.

https://github.com/smol-rs/async-process.git.

In the crates.io page it says I can put it in my project's Cargo.toml as:

```
[dependencies]
async-process = "2.0.1"
```

And in my rust code as:

```
use async_process::Command; // this fails to find the "crate"
```

Well this doesn't work.

when building, the crate is retrieved and compiled but compiling the code gives this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `async_process`
 --> build.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use async_process::Command;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `async_process`?
  |
  = help: consider adding `extern crate async_process` to use the `async_process` crate
```

I then tried:

```
extern crate async_process;
```

And get this error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `async_process`
 --> build.rs:4:1
  |
4 | extern crate async_process;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

How is this supposed to work ?
is it some restriction placed on build.rs ?

The reason I want this is I am using the build.rs to spawn a command to run a rather log process and want to log it's stdout to a file ( or print to the console while running ) the async-process::Command offered a way to do this, that is if I can use it.

Comment: Wait, is this code in build.rs?

Answer (score 0):

In the cargo.toml, use a dash.

```ini
[dependencies]
async-process = "2.0.1"
```

In the code, use an underscore.

```rust
use async_process::Command;
```

That should work.

If in doubt, the crate's page on [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/async-process) will list the name that should be used in Cargo.toml on the right hand side.

When including a crate in code, always use underscores instead of dashes.

Comment: That does not work here.  The first thing I tried because as you said it is what is stated on the grates.io page.

Cargo.toml

    [dependencies]
    async-process = { git = "https://github.com/smol-rs/async-process.git", version = "2.0.1" }

In the rust code as you said,  But I get this error:

error[E0432]: unresolved import `async_process`
 --> build.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use async_process::Command;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `async_process`?
  |
  = help: consider adding `extern crate async_process` to use the `async_process` crate

Comment: I also tried: 

[dependencies]
async-process = "2.0.1"

instead of using the url